# Extract Point From Raster in GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I have a raster file and a WGS84 lat/lon point.

I would like to know what value in the raster corresponds with the point.

My feeling is that I should use `GetSpatialRef()` on the raster object or one of its bands and then apply a `ogr.osr.CoordinateTransformation()` to the point to map it to the raster's space.

My hope would then be that I could simply ask the rasters' bands what is at that point.

However, the raster object doesn't seem to have a `GetSpatialRef()` or a way to access a geo-located point, so I'm somewhat at a loss for how to do this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Say i have a geotiff file test.tif.  Then followin code should look up value somewhere near the pixel.  I am not that confident for the part looking up cell, and will fix there is error.  This page should help, ["GDAL Data Model"](http://openev.sourceforge.net/app/developer_info/COURSE1_gdal_datamodel.html)

Also, you may go to [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) to find experts, if you haven't.

```
import gdal, osr

class looker(object):
    """let you look up pixel value"""

    def __init__(self, tifname='test.tif'):
       """Give name of tif file (or other raster data?)"""

        # open the raster and its spatial reference
        self.ds = gdal.Open(tifname)
        srRaster = osr.SpatialReference(self.ds.GetProjection())

        # get the WGS84 spatial reference
        srPoint = osr.SpatialReference()
        srPoint.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # WGS84

        # coordinate transformation
        self.ct = osr.CoordinateTransformation(srPoint, srRaster)

        # geotranformation and its inverse
        gt = self.ds.GetGeoTransform()
        dev = (gt[1]*gt[5] - gt[2]*gt[4])
        gtinv = ( gt[0] , gt[5]/dev, -gt[2]/dev, 
                gt[3], -gt[4]/dev, gt[1]/dev)
        self.gt = gt
        self.gtinv = gtinv

        # band as array
        b = self.ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        self.arr = b.ReadAsArray()

    def lookup(self, lon, lat):
        """look up value at lon, lat"""

        # get coordinate of the raster
        xgeo,ygeo,zgeo = self.ct.TransformPoint(lon, lat, 0)

        # convert it to pixel/line on band
        u = xgeo - self.gtinv[0]
        v = ygeo - self.gtinv[3]
        # FIXME this int() is probably bad idea, there should be 
        # half cell size thing needed
        xpix =  int(self.gtinv[1] * u + self.gtinv[2] * v)
        ylin = int(self.gtinv[4] * u + self.gtinv[5] * v)

        # look the value up
        return self.arr[ylin,xpix]

# test
l = looker('test.tif')
lon,lat = -100,30
print l.lookup(lon,lat)

lat,lon =28.816944, -96.993333
print l.lookup(lon,lat)
```

Comment: I don't follow the logic used to calculate `dev` or `gtinv` in your constructor. Can you explain? Also, it would be nice to know how to deal with different projections in your `ImportFromEPSG(4326)` statement. Thanks.

Comment: I believe I had inverse matrix of geo-transformation matrix, and then when I got lon/lat, I back-calculated the pixel/line

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the API isn't consistent. The raster (the data source) has a `GetProjection()` method instead (which returns WKT).

Here is a function that does what you want (drawn from [here](https://github.com/openmeteo/pthelma/blob/87aeed3a6c680eacb502b582bfe78f3ece6087f6/pthelma/spatial.py#L175)):

```
def extract_point_from_raster(point, data_source, band_number=1):
    """Return floating-point value that corresponds to given point."""

    # Convert point co-ordinates so that they are in same projection as raster
    point_sr = point.GetSpatialReference()
    raster_sr = osr.SpatialReference()
    raster_sr.ImportFromWkt(data_source.GetProjection())
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(point_sr, raster_sr)
    point.Transform(transform)

    # Convert geographic co-ordinates to pixel co-ordinates
    x, y = point.GetX(), point.GetY()
    forward_transform = Affine.from_gdal(*data_source.GetGeoTransform())
    reverse_transform = ~forward_transform
    px, py = reverse_transform * (x, y)
    px, py = int(px + 0.5), int(py + 0.5)

    # Extract pixel value
    band = data_source.GetRasterBand(band_number)
    structval = band.ReadRaster(px, py, 1, 1, buf_type=gdal.GDT_Float32)
    result = struct.unpack('f', structval)[0]
    if result == band.GetNoDataValue():
        result = float('nan')
    return result
```

Its documentation is as follows (drawn from [here](http://pthelma.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/spatial.html#spatial.extract_point_from_raster)):

```
spatial.extract_point_from_raster(point, data_source, band_number=1)
```

> data_source is a GDAL raster, and point is an OGR point object. The
>   function returns the value of the pixel of the specified band of
>   data_source that is nearest to point.
>
> point and data_source need not be in the same reference system, but
>   they must both have an appropriate spatial reference defined.
>
> If the point does not fall in the raster, RuntimeError is raised.

Answer (score -1):

```
project = self.ds.GetProjection()
srPoint = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=project)
```

done... with that, the vector file has adopted the projection from input raster file