# Retrieve polygon label from shape file based on latitude and longitude

Tags: python, geospatial, shapefile

I am new to working with geospatial data in Python, and I need some help with what I hope is a simple task.

I have a shape file of New York City Police Precincts, which can be found [here](https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Public-Safety/Police-Precincts/78dh-3ptz), and I have a dataframe with two columns, ‘Latitude’ and ‘Longitude’, that are associated with NYC 311 call incident locations. Unfortunately, 311 data does not contain a Police Precinct column, so I am hoping to add that feature myself.

I believe I need to retrieve the polygon label (i.e. ‘5th Precinct’ - or however it phrased) for a given Lat,Long coordinate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861196/check-if-a-geopoint-with-latitude-and-longitude-is-within-a-shapefile